# Should I check first and plan accordingly or should I check for every data?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So. I am  writing a code for an assignment. I have a big set of data (which contains gender, occupation and weigh), and it is classified (roughly) as student/nonstudent and masculine/feminine.

I am asked to filter through the data (already did, using a function with parametres) so I can get:

- A list with every weight
- A list with every student's weight
- A list with every masculine student's weight
- A list with every feminine student's weight
- A list with every non student's weight

but a doubt came to my mind: should I iterate through every element of the big list and check for every element, or should I create a piece of code for every restriction? Which one is the most efficient/pythonic thing to do?

The data is arranged in sublists like

```
['E', '23', 'M', 'AC', 96.5, 0.69, '130.28']
```

where, in order, it tells if student/nonstudent, age, gender, if before/after eating, weight, the expected error of the measurement of the weight and the hour when it was measured.

For now I am iterating first and checking later with the following code.

```
def datafilter(fil=False,est=None,sex=None):
    Data=[]
    if not fil:
        for q in dreal():
            for w in q:
                Data.append(w[4])
        return Data
    if fil:
        for q in dreal():
            for w in q:
                if est is True and w[0]=='E':
                    if sex is None:
                        Data.append(w[4])
                    if w[2]==sex:
                        Data.append(w[4])
                if est is False and w[0]!='E':
                    Data.append(w[4])
        return Data
```

Comment: It's poor design to use lists for this -- all those hard-coded indexes make the code difficult to understand. Use objects or dictionaries so you can use `w.weight` or `w['weight']` instead of `w[4]`.

Comment: What do you mean: "or should I create a piece of code for every restriction?"

Comment: most of this is one liners with pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define filter functions:

```
def datafilter(fil=False, est=None, sex=None):
    if not fil:
        filter = lambda w: True
    elif est:
        if sex:
            filter = lambda w: w[0] == 'E' and w[2] == sex
        else:
            filter = lambda w: w[0] == 'E'
    else:
        filter = lambda w: w[0] != 'E' 
    return [w[4] for q in dreal() for w in q if filter(w)]
```